# The image becomes larger when it is added to a WPF page?

Tags: wpf, image

I've got an image with 400 * 400 pixels. Now, when I add it to the WPF page:

```
<Image Source="Resources\about.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

its size become larger:

[image]

Any idea why this behavior happens?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the width and height explicitly:

```
<Image Source="Resources\about.png" Width="400" Height="400" />
```

(Also, in your screenshot, it looks like `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` are set to `Stretch`?)